# Mirroring between on-premises MySQL to azure MySQL database?

Tags: mysql, azure, mariadb

Can we establish mirroring between on-premises mysql to azure mysql database? Will this require downtime on master side?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set-up [Data-In replication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/mysql/howto-data-in-replication) between an on-premise MySQL instance and an Azure Database for MySQL instance but, as for mirroring, you could set-up a redundant solution all in Azure or all on-premise. If by "mirroring" you mean 'replication' or 'copying', the Data-In replication method linked above is possibly what you are looking for.